# Is there a way to rebuild/repair ASP.Net personalization tables without losing the data inside?

Tags: asp.net, web-parts, personalization

I inherited an Asp.Net app that uses ASP.Net membership services.  I am trying to add web parts with personalization to the site, and am getting a lot of errors.  It looks like the tables generated by Aspnet_regsql.exe have been changed - probably copied at some point in the past using "select into" causing them to lose all their indexes and primary keys.

How can I repair these tables without losing all the data inside?

Answer (score 1):

1. Backup database (just in case!)
2. Rename existing database
3. Recreate aspnetdb
4. Bulk copy data from renamed DB into newly recreated DB. (probably with BCP)

I know BCP is an old tool... but it still works.  Maybe there is an easier way to do it, but this is how I would do it.